# HTML Mails in Dark Mode

Tags: html, css, frontend, darkmode

I'm working on an email project and need to display email body in dark mode.
The email body is an HTML with defined color styles.
My goal is to flip the text and background color to display it in dark mode.
Define a dark scheme style like this

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html {
        filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
    }

    img, video {
        filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg);
    }
}
```

After flipping the colors overall, flipping the pictures and videos back looks like the result is good.
The only flaw is that this flips the colors of the emojis as well, which makes them look horrible.

[image]

I also tried mixing colors.

```
   color: white;
   mix-blend-mode: screen;
```

This will also brighten the colors of emojis. And it does not make black texts appear white.

It comes down to a question: How to make the following text appear in white, and keep emojis displaying normally.

```
<div style="color: black;">
      Hello world!    
</div>
```

Expected result:

[image]

--- Edited ---

A good example is the Apple mail app:

[image]

Send a mail with HTML:

```
<div>Test colors: </div>
<div style="color: black;">Black</div>
<div style="color: green;">Green</div>
<div style="color: red;">Red</div>
<div style="color: pink;">Pink</div>
<div style="color: blue;">Blue</div>
<div style="color: yellow;">Yellow</div>
<div style="color: gray;">Grey</div>
<div style="color: white;">White</div>
<div style="color: #8300bb;">Purple</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use the usual CSS? `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { html { background: black; color: white; } }`

Comment: This does not override the color definition in style. Even if add a !important tag, it will make all colors white. Actually the Apple mail app can keep displaying multiple colors in dark mode.

Comment: Do you mean it's a specificity issue or the app just doesn't allow you to change it?

Comment: Because the HTML of the incoming email is uncontrolled, changes can only be made based on it. As a mail app I can control the display of the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your emojis in a span with a class of emoji. Then, in CSS, along with the body, you should invert it.

If you invert something that is inverted, it goes back to normal! :)

I think you need something like this:

```css
html {
     background: white;
     color: black;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    html {
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    .emoji { 
        filter: invert(1); 
    }
}
```

```html
<div> Hello world! 
    <span class="emoji">  </span> 
</div>
```